# ios 7 transition color bug when changing color of navigation title

Tags: ios, ios7, transition, navigationbar

Ok this one had me make a new test project to see if the problem was still there. It was. So I've made a very simple app with two view controllers and views. The first view with a button that pushed to the second view. The second view changes the navigation bar title color to red with this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setTitle:@"SecondView"];

//sets navBar TITLE color and font
NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIColor redColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;}
```

Default view1 title color is green and nav bar is black. (set this to see what i mean)

Problem is when going back with the automatically created back button on the nav bar, the title briefly show the old Green color for a few mili seconds before fading to the new red color. Ive tried calling viewWillAppear and re-setting the color of the navigation bar title, but it doenst even work. Isn't this a bug?

EDIT i also tried changing color of previous navigation bar by delegating... same thing.. wtf? This must be a bug clearly..!

EDIT EDIT: i realize now that its the transition effect that goes from black(always black) --> to custom color ONLY if  you're going back to an already stacked view.

Comment: Do you test it on device or in simulator?

Comment: Both simulator and iPhone..

Comment: Try it out for yourself. If you change the navbar title color in a view that is not the main view, when u go back, the title flashes the old color a few mili seconds before fading in to the new color

Comment: There is a slide animation with a final cross-fade during the view controller transition from SecondView to FirstView....in order to support the left-right slide gesture for a back transition, there must be a snapshot of the FirstView to slide in.  Custom view controller transitions might be your ticket?

Comment: yea thats what i am looking into now, but i really think its a bug. Its only when views are pushed on top of each other, you change color and go back a view... Could i new the navigation bar in the first view before going back to it or something? setting the color an extra time in delegate method of viewwillappear still makes the first view flash the color briefly

Comment: You could try removing the title text (or setting alpha=0?) as you transition away, then restore it when you transition back?, but this will be imperfect at best.  you could set the navbar title color before the transition also?

Comment: i will try that also... but i have tried re-setting the color in the viewwillappear method of the first view. The color is the right color, but  flashes the old color before the transition ends

Comment: i realize now that its the transition effect that goes from black(always black) --> to custom color ONLY if  you're going back to an already stacked view.

Comment: So how did you fix it?